# Dynamically define the (keyword) arguments to a function?

Tags: python, function, metaprogramming

Is it possible to **define** the keyword arguments to a function dynamically?

Normally you have something like this:

```
def f(a=None, b=None):
    return locals()
```

What I want is to define a function with the keyword args from a dict; so this would give the same function as above:

```
dyn_args = {'a': None, 'b': None}
def f(?magic(dyn_args)?):
    return locals()
```

The reason is I want the function to only accept kwargs that match the fields of a namedtuple, and error on anything else.  The function should work with a few different namedtuples (and if they change), and I'd like to keep it DRY.  I can work around it with kwargs and validation, but mostly I'm just curious -- dirty hacks welcome.

Comment: Why not just use `**kwargs` in the function, and check any required ones?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a decorator.

Comment: What's the content of the function? Have a look at the `FunctionDef` in the `ast` module. In my opinion these are dirty hacks in your case... I think kwargs would be the best solution..

Answer (score 1):

It seems fastcore's `use_kwargs` decorator does just what you're asking for:

https://fastcore.fast.ai/meta.html#use_kwargs

To see how this is implemented, you can just have a look at its code in github:

https://github.com/fastai/fastcore/blob/master/fastcore/meta.py#L95

There is also a similar decorator, `use_kwargs_dict`, which also indicates the default values to be used.